# How Do I Properly Install Selinux on Ubuntu?

Tags: apparmor, selinux

In the past I have used Fedora and loved having Selinux and learning about it etc. I'm pretty familiar with it. But I had a soft spot in my heart and went back to Ubuntu due to it being the first distro I used. I know that Apparmor is similar and installed on Ubuntu by default however I wish to use what I'm used to. Does anyone have an update to date guide on how to safely and properly remove apparmor and install Selinux? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: BTW, good story.

Comment: Although you can install selinux in ubuntu, it is not as supported as selinux in fedora. I suggest you either use apparmor or stay with fedora if you want selinux